# javascript regex replace expressions found with themselves within tags

Tags: javascript, html, regex, forms, replace

I have a form where a user can enter in some code, and then I want to use Javascript to display it back to them in the webpage. I've already used regex in javascript to replace all the < > tags with html keywords &lt and &gt, but I want to highlight in blue all instances of a tag being opened and then ending with a space or a close tag. I can find the expressions I want but I then want to surround each of them with < span> tags.

The actual code is long but Here's some example code that covers what I want to do:

```
    //example of what a user might put in
    var text = "<div id='main'>Here is some <b>bold</b> text.</div>";
    //Replace all tag symbols with html keywords
    text = text.replace(/\r?</g,'&lt');
    //now the expression to get what i want to highlight blue
    var regExp = /\&lt[a-zA-Z]+(\s|&gt)/g;
```

And now I want to find the expressions, and replace them all with themselves wrapped inside span tags, like:

```
    text = text.replace(regExp,"<span class='bluefont'>EACH EXPRESSION FOUND</span>");
```

I don't know how to do this or if it's even possible just using replace, but it would be really handy if it is.

I know there are external libraries for syntax highlighting but I don't want to use any external libraries for this. I'm using [a-zA-Z] instead of checking for legal tag names in html because I want this to work for xml/xhtml too.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple solution - replace all < and > with entites, next use regexp `(\&lt;[a-zA-Z]*\&gt;)`. But to be exact I would use something else for first replacement, like below.

```js
markedString = htmlentities('My cat is <span>fluffy</span>')
markedString = markedString.replace(new RegExp('(\&lt;[a-zA-Z]*\&gt;)', 'g'), '<span class="marked">$1</span>');


function htmlentities (string, quote_style, charset, double_encode) {    
  var hash_map = this.get_html_translation_table('HTML_ENTITIES', quote_style),
    symbol = '';
  string = string == null ? '' : string + '';    
  if (!hash_map) {
    return false;
  }

  if (quote_style && quote_style === 'ENT_QUOTES') {
    hash_map["'"] = '&#039;';
  }

  if (!!double_encode || double_encode == null) {
    for (symbol in hash_map) {
      if (hash_map.hasOwnProperty(symbol)) {
        string = string.split(symbol).join(hash_map[symbol]);
      }
    }
  } else {
    string = string.replace(/([\s\S]*?)(&(?:#\d+|#x[\da-f]+|[a-zA-Z][\da-z]*);|$)/g, function (ignore, text, entity) {
      for (symbol in hash_map) {
        if (hash_map.hasOwnProperty(symbol)) {
          text = text.split(symbol).join(hash_map[symbol]);
        }
      }

      return text + entity;
    });
  }

  return string;
}
function get_html_translation_table (table, quote_style) {
  var entities = {},
    hash_map = {},
    decimal;
  var constMappingTable = {},
    constMappingQuoteStyle = {};
  var useTable = {},
    useQuoteStyle = {};

  // Translate arguments
  constMappingTable[0] = 'HTML_SPECIALCHARS';
  constMappingTable[1] = 'HTML_ENTITIES';
  constMappingQuoteStyle[0] = 'ENT_NOQUOTES';
  constMappingQuoteStyle[2] = 'ENT_COMPAT';
  constMappingQuoteStyle[3] = 'ENT_QUOTES';

  useTable = !isNaN(table) ? constMappingTable[table] : table ? table.toUpperCase() : 'HTML_SPECIALCHARS';
  useQuoteStyle = !isNaN(quote_style) ? constMappingQuoteStyle[quote_style] : quote_style ? quote_style.toUpperCase() : 'ENT_COMPAT';

  if (useTable !== 'HTML_SPECIALCHARS' && useTable !== 'HTML_ENTITIES') {
    throw new Error("Table: " + useTable + ' not supported');
    // return false;
  }

  entities['38'] = '&amp;';
  if (useTable === 'HTML_ENTITIES') {
    entities['160'] = '&nbsp;';
    entities['161'] = '&iexcl;';
    entities['162'] = '&cent;';
    entities['163'] = '&pound;';
    entities['164'] = '&curren;';
    entities['165'] = '&yen;';
    entities['166'] = '&brvbar;';
    entities['167'] = '&sect;';
    entities['168'] = '&uml;';
    entities['169'] = '&copy;';
    entities['170'] = '&ordf;';
    entities['171'] = '&laquo;';
    entities['172'] = '&not;';
    entities['173'] = '&shy;';
    entities['174'] = '&reg;';
    entities['175'] = '&macr;';
    entities['176'] = '&deg;';
    entities['177'] = '&plusmn;';
    entities['178'] = '&sup2;';
    entities['179'] = '&sup3;';
    entities['180'] = '&acute;';
    entities['181'] = '&micro;';
    entities['182'] = '&para;';
    entities['183'] = '&middot;';
    entities['184'] = '&cedil;';
    entities['185'] = '&sup1;';
    entities['186'] = '&ordm;';
    entities['187'] = '&raquo;';
    entities['188'] = '&frac14;';
    entities['189'] = '&frac12;';
    entities['190'] = '&frac34;';
    entities['191'] = '&iquest;';
    entities['192'] = '&Agrave;';
    entities['193'] = '&Aacute;';
    entities['194'] = '&Acirc;';
    entities['195'] = '&Atilde;';
    entities['196'] = '&Auml;';
    entities['197'] = '&Aring;';
    entities['198'] = '&AElig;';
    entities['199'] = '&Ccedil;';
    entities['200'] = '&Egrave;';
    entities['201'] = '&Eacute;';
    entities['202'] = '&Ecirc;';
    entities['203'] = '&Euml;';
    entities['204'] = '&Igrave;';
    entities['205'] = '&Iacute;';
    entities['206'] = '&Icirc;';
    entities['207'] = '&Iuml;';
    entities['208'] = '&ETH;';
    entities['209'] = '&Ntilde;';
    entities['210'] = '&Ograve;';
    entities['211'] = '&Oacute;';
    entities['212'] = '&Ocirc;';
    entities['213'] = '&Otilde;';
    entities['214'] = '&Ouml;';
    entities['215'] = '&times;';
    entities['216'] = '&Oslash;';
    entities['217'] = '&Ugrave;';
    entities['218'] = '&Uacute;';
    entities['219'] = '&Ucirc;';
    entities['220'] = '&Uuml;';
    entities['221'] = '&Yacute;';
    entities['222'] = '&THORN;';
    entities['223'] = '&szlig;';
    entities['224'] = '&agrave;';
    entities['225'] = '&aacute;';
    entities['226'] = '&acirc;';
    entities['227'] = '&atilde;';
    entities['228'] = '&auml;';
    entities['229'] = '&aring;';
    entities['230'] = '&aelig;';
    entities['231'] = '&ccedil;';
    entities['232'] = '&egrave;';
    entities['233'] = '&eacute;';
    entities['234'] = '&ecirc;';
    entities['235'] = '&euml;';
    entities['236'] = '&igrave;';
    entities['237'] = '&iacute;';
    entities['238'] = '&icirc;';
    entities['239'] = '&iuml;';
    entities['240'] = '&eth;';
    entities['241'] = '&ntilde;';
    entities['242'] = '&ograve;';
    entities['243'] = '&oacute;';
    entities['244'] = '&ocirc;';
    entities['245'] = '&otilde;';
    entities['246'] = '&ouml;';
    entities['247'] = '&divide;';
    entities['248'] = '&oslash;';
    entities['249'] = '&ugrave;';
    entities['250'] = '&uacute;';
    entities['251'] = '&ucirc;';
    entities['252'] = '&uuml;';
    entities['253'] = '&yacute;';
    entities['254'] = '&thorn;';
    entities['255'] = '&yuml;';
  }

  if (useQuoteStyle !== 'ENT_NOQUOTES') {
    entities['34'] = '&quot;';
  }
  if (useQuoteStyle === 'ENT_QUOTES') {
    entities['39'] = '&#39;';
  }
  entities['60'] = '&lt;';
  entities['62'] = '&gt;';


  // ascii decimals to real symbols
  for (decimal in entities) {
    if (entities.hasOwnProperty(decimal)) {
      hash_map[String.fromCharCode(decimal)] = entities[decimal];
    }
  }

  return hash_map;
}
```

function **htmlentites** from http://phpjs.org/functions/htmlentities/

function **get_html_translation_table** from http://phpjs.org/functions/get_html_translation_table/

Answer (score 0):

I'm no regex expert, but I believe you could do it using backreferences in your regular expression.

```
var regExp = /(\&lt[a-zA-Z]+(\s|&gt))/g; //Note the additional parentheses
text = text.replace(regExp,"<span class='bluefont'>$1</span>");
```